# initialize Convex.MaxAtom array Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, convex

How can I create an `Array` of `Convex.MaxAtom`s (or for that matter, other `Convex` types) with the `Convex` package? I'm not sure if an `Array` is the right structure, but what I want to do is initialize something `my_array` of length `n` so that I can update each element in a loop like

```
using Convex
v = Variable(n)
w = Variable(n)
my_array = ...initialized array?...
for i = 1:n
    my_array[i] = max(v[i],w[i])
end
```

I've tried doing

```
my_array = Convex.MaxAtom[]
for i = 1:n
    push!(x, max(v[i], w[i]))
end
```

but I want to avoid reallocating memory and do it upfront. I feel that I must be missing an important part of Julia in not understanding what types to use to construct this.

Comment: Maybe `a = Vector{Convex.MaxAtom}(n)` (but haven't tested this)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Would you like to write this up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia `Vector{AnyType}(n)` (replace AnyType with a valid type in the application) allocates a vector of uninitialized AnyType elements of length `n`. More generally, `Array{AnyType,3}(2,3,4)` would allocate a 3-dimensional tensor of size 2x3x4 and analogously any dimension or shape can be allocated.

For the case in the question, a solution would be:

```
a = Vector{Convex.MaxAtom}(n)
```

P.S. the elements are allocated but uninitialized, this is fast, but it may be safer to use `fill(some_value, n)` or `zero(AnyType, n)` (which requires `zero(AnyType)` to be defined).